# java overflow during vector norm calculation with long

Tags: java, overflow, long-integer

I have a simple way to calculate the norm of a 2dim Vector using 2 longs: (example)

```
long x = 4294967296L;
long y = 0L;
long result;
result = (long) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
```

My Problem is that I have numbers so that they fit in x, y and result. But there is an overflow calculating x*x and y*y.

Is there any simple method to avoid this or do i have to use BigInteger?

Comment: `Is there any simple method to avoid this or do i have to use BigInteger?` No. use BigInteger.

Answer (score 1):

BigInteger should be your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You should use BigInteger for calculations.